# Delay in execution of step function when I have multiple cloudwatch rules triggering same step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

We have setup a process where multiple cloudwatch rules trigger same step function.We have defined 10 cloudwatch rules and all of them trigger same step function after every 30 mins.But I see that the step function is triggered at different time instead all 10 starting at same time.Ex

cloudwatch rule 1 --  Stepfunction trigger at (08:00:10)

cloudwatch rule 2 --  Stepfunction trigger at (08:00:20)

cloudwatch rule 3 --  Stepfunction trigger at (08:00:25)

cloudwatch rule 4 --  Stepfunction trigger at (08:00:34)

cloudwatch rule 5 --  Stepfunction trigger at (08:00:40) and so on..

Does anyone know the reason for the difference in seconds.We want the process to complete with in 5 mins but if last cloudwatch rule triggers the step function after 1 min than the actual time then it would delay the process

Answer (score 1):

Triggering variability is expected.  For [CloudWatch cron schedule rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html), for instance, *"Due to the distributed nature of the CloudWatch Events and the target services ... your scheduled rule is triggered within that minute, but not on the precise 0th second."*

You could try combining the events into a single event and using a step functions [Map state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) to process them concurrently in a single execution.